# React page blank in browser after Azure DevOps pipeline deployment to Azure Linux Web App

Tags: reactjs, azure, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service, azure-appservice

Just started my career in the field of DevOps. First project and I have been tasked with is deploying 2 node JS React Web Apps to an Azure App Service Linux Web App.

The first application deployed fine and came up no problem. I then cloned the pipeline for the second app and the pipeline completed with no errors, but the app is not displaying anything in the browser.

The developer working on the project tells me that the apps are near on indentical so I am a bit lost in trying to work out why it is not working. I can view the files on the web app and not seeing any obvious errors there although I may not be looking in the correct place.

Here is my build and deployment pipeline:

```
trigger:
- main

variables:

  # Azure Resource Manager connection created during pipeline creation
  azureSubscription: '3d20b47e-76d8-4913-9809-a463ae10f0b3'

  # Web app name
  webAppName: 'app-pblp-dev'

  # Environment name
  environmentName: 'dev'

  # Agent VM image name
  vmImageName: 'ubuntu-latest'

stages:
- stage: Build
  displayName: Build stage
  jobs:
  - job: Build
    displayName: Build
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)

    steps:
    - task: NodeTool@0
      inputs:
        versionSource: 'spec'
        versionSpec: '20.x'
        checkLatest: true
      displayName: 'Install Node.js'

    - script: |
       cd ./frontend/pbl-management-portal-ui
       npm install
      displayName: 'npm install'

    - script: |
       cd ./frontend/pbl-management-portal-ui
       npm run build
      displayName: 'npm build'

    - task: ArchiveFiles@2
      displayName: 'Archive files'
      inputs:
        rootFolderOrFile: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/frontend/pbl-management-portal-ui'
        includeRootFolder: false
        archiveType: zip
        archiveFile: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip
        replaceExistingArchive: true

    - upload: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip
      artifact: drop

- stage: Deploy
  displayName: Deploy stage
  dependsOn: Build
  condition: succeeded()
  jobs:
  - deployment: Deploy
    displayName: Deploy
    environment: $(environmentName)
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)
    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:
          - task: AzureRmWebAppDeployment@4
            displayName: 'Azure App Service Deploy: Management Portal React Front End'
            inputs:
              azureSubscription: $(azureSubscription)
              appType: webAppLinux
              WebAppName: $(webAppName)
              packageForLinux: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/drop/$(Build.BuildId).zip'
              RuntimeStack: 'NODE|20-lts'
              StartupCommand: 'pm2 serve /home/site/wwwroot/public --no-daemon --spa'
```

Update found these errors in the logs for the app service:

Error
2023-12-14T15:16:28.637
ERROR - Container app-pblp-dev_0_3406cf6e for site app-pblp-dev did not start within expected time limit. Elapsed time = 230.1702239 sec

Container app-pblp-dev_0_34fce3c4 didn't respond to HTTP pings on port: 8080, failing site start. See container logs for debugging.

Comment: Welcome to SO. You are reaching out to the subcommunity with `Azure DevOps` tag. However, Azure DevOps is simply an automation tool where you can integrate the build and deployment of you nodes.js app in the pipeline workflow. Can you let us know if there is any error during your pipeline agent job? If not, we may probably rule out the cause of the issue by the automation tool, right?

Comment: To further isolate the cause of your issue, may I know if you have tested to deploy to Azure App Service from your local machine for example via [AzureCLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/webapp?view=azure-cli-latest#az-webapp-deploy) and if the issue is reproducible? What is the behavior when you build and deploy your application from local environment? If the issue is related to your app code and how to configure your app hosting on Azure, please add respective tag like `azure-appservice`. Thx for the sharing.

Comment: @AlvinZhao there are no errors on the pipeline build or deployment steps. Only some minor warnings about dependencies. I've updated the tags to include app service now. Hopefully someone can reach out as I am seeing some errors in that service

Comment: @AlvinZhao I've not tried deploying it with Azure Cli from my local machine. I will investigate this today

Comment: Hi there, have you got a chance to check the answer by @SiddheshDesai below? Does it work to resolve the issue from your side? In case the issue persists, would you share your artifact file structure under `Advanced tools` -> `Go` -> `Site wwwroot` to double check the correct path to run your startup command? Thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you are using the correct build folder in your start up command, Instead of using
**`pm2 serve /home/site/wwwroot/public --no-daemon --spa`**, Use - ***`pm2 serve /home/site/wwwroot/build/ --no-daemon --spa`*** OR **`npm run start`**.

***My Azure DevOps yaml pipeline:-***

**With npm run start**:-

```yaml
trigger:
- main

variables:

  
  azureSubscription: 'xxxxxx'

  # Web app name
  webAppName: 'valleywebApp98'

  # Environment name
  environmentName: 'valleysilicon'

  # Agent VM image name
  vmImageName: 'ubuntu-latest'

stages:
- stage: Build
  displayName: Build stage
  jobs:
  - job: Build
    displayName: Build
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)

    steps:
    - task: ArchiveFiles@2
      displayName: 'Archive files'
      inputs:
        rootFolderOrFile: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
        includeRootFolder: false
        archiveType: zip
        archiveFile: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip
        replaceExistingArchive: true

    - upload: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip
      artifact: drop

- stage: Deploy
  displayName: Deploy stage
  dependsOn: Build
  condition: succeeded()
  jobs:
  - deployment: Deploy
    displayName: Deploy
    environment: $(environmentName)
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)
    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:
          - task: AzureRmWebAppDeployment@4
            displayName: 'Azure App Service Deploy: valleysilicon'
            inputs:
              azureSubscription: $(azureSubscription)
              appType: webAppLinux
              WebAppName: $(webAppName)
              packageForLinux: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/drop/$(Build.BuildId).zip'
              RuntimeStack: 'NODE|20.0.0'
              StartupCommand: 'npm run start'
              ScriptType: 'Inline Script'
              InlineScript: |
                npm install
                npm run build --if-present
```

**Output:-**

[image]

[image]

[image]

With ***`pm2 serve /home/site/wwwroot/build/ --no-daemon --spa`***

***Azure DevOps YAML pipeline:-***

```yaml
trigger:
- main

variables:

  
  azureSubscription: 'xxxxxxx'

  # Web app name
  webAppName: 'valleywebApp98'

  # Environment name
  environmentName: 'valleysilicon'

  # Agent VM image name
  vmImageName: 'ubuntu-latest'

stages:
- stage: Build
  displayName: Build stage
  jobs:
  - job: Build
    displayName: Build
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)

    steps:
    - task: ArchiveFiles@2
      displayName: 'Archive files'
      inputs:
        rootFolderOrFile: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
        includeRootFolder: false
        archiveType: zip
        archiveFile: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip
        replaceExistingArchive: true

    - upload: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip
      artifact: drop

- stage: Deploy
  displayName: Deploy stage
  dependsOn: Build
  condition: succeeded()
  jobs:
  - deployment: Deploy
    displayName: Deploy
    environment: $(environmentName)
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)
    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:
          - task: AzureRmWebAppDeployment@4
            displayName: 'Azure App Service Deploy: valleysilicon'
            inputs:
              azureSubscription: $(azureSubscription)
              appType: webAppLinux
              WebAppName: $(webAppName)
              packageForLinux: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/drop/$(Build.BuildId).zip'
              RuntimeStack: 'NODE|20.0.0'
              StartupCommand: 'pm2 serve /home/site/wwwroot/build/ --no-daemon --spa'
              ScriptType: 'Inline Script'
              InlineScript: |
                npm install
                npm run build --if-present
```

***Start up command:-***

[image]

[image]

You can verify your build path by visiting **`Advanced tools > Go > Site wwwroot >`**:-

[image]
My Azure Web App Properties:-

[image]

Comment: yes is worked when I changed the path of the pm2 serve command to point to the build folder. I am not sure why the other app worked on the public folder